# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops

Using Powershell in Azure DevOps release pipeline, I am trying to convert parameters into json format before posting to a asp netcore endpoint. One of the parameters is datetime.

I am getting the following error for the DateTime type:

```
"errors":{"$.CreatedDate":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime].
```

Here is the Powershell script. The variable `$(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.STARTTIME)` is a DevOps variable and outputs the date format `2020-06-15 10:00:46Z`

```
$params = @{   
   Name = "Test"
    CreatedDate = $(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.STARTTIME) 
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://mynetcoreendpoint -Method POST -Body ($params | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
```

The json is evaluated at the endpoint side. Here is the NetCore endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<ReleaseDTO> CreateRelease(ReleaseDTO release)
 {
    // Do some stuff
 }

 // Where ReleaseDTO has the property 

 public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: And as what do you want your date get passed? As a string like you posted or as an integer (unix timestamp) or something else?

Comment: I am passing it as a string format but the netcore type is C# a nullable DateTime? createdDate.

Comment: But the error is not thrown by the code provided, correct? The error occurs where the received JSON is evaluated. Could you post the evaluating code?

Comment: @doorman When `$(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.STARTTIME)` is expanded, does it include enclosing _quotes_? Perhaps you need to provide these quotes yourself.

Comment: $(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.STARTTIME) comes without the quotes, I tried adding enclsing quotes but same error. I also tried the DateTime casting also didn´t work.

Comment: @Thomas please see the updated code with the endpoint where the validation happens by .netcore

Comment: @doorman What happens if you replace `CreatedDate` by `DateTime.Parse(CreatedDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` in your NetCore code?

Comment: doorman: If the expanded macro value isn't enclosed in quotes and you don't supply them yourself, the `$params =  ...` statement would _break_. A cast such as `[datetime] '2020-06-15 10:00:46Z'` _does_ work, so perhaps your value has hidden characters? @Thomas' implied question is also worth exploring - what format does the implicit JSON deserialization layer expect? I've undeleted my answer, and I've added  some general pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the hashtable that is the basis for the to-JSON conversion contains a `[datetime]` instance, not just a *string*:

```
# !! This may work in PowerShell [Core, v6+] only, not in Windows PowerShell.
$params = @{   
  Name = "Test"
  # Note the cast to [datetime] and the need to enclose the
  # Azure macro in quotes.
  CreatedDate = [datetime] '$(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.STARTTIME)'
}
```

That way, the JSON representation of the timestamp should deserialize properly in the endpoint's C#-based code - *assuming that both the serializing code and the deserializing code use the same string-based convention for representing `[datetime]` instances*<sup>[1]</sup>

---

**If you're using *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1) and the web-service end-point uses .NET Core / Json.NET, the conventions are *mismatched*, so you need to create the string representation of the timestamp as required by the web-service endpoint *manually***:

```
$params = @{   
  Name = "Test"
  # Note the cast to [datetime] and the need to enclose the
  # Azure macro in quotes.
  CreatedDate = ([datetime] '$(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.STARTTIME)').ToString('o')
}
```

Read on for an explanation.

---

Unfortunately, there are different conventions in the .NET world with respect to how timestamps are represented in JSON:

- On the PowerShell side (verify with `@{ dt = [datetime]::now } | ConvertTo-Json`):

  - *Windows PowerShell*: `ConvertTo-Json` uses the convention of `"\/Date(<epochTimeMs>)\/"`, where `<epochTimeMs>` is a Unix epoch timestamp in milliseconds.

    - Example: `@{ dt = [datetime]::now } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress` yields
      `{"dt":"\/Date(1592309341640)\/"}`
  - *PowerShell* [Core, v6+], as of version 7.0: `ConvertTo-Json` uses Json.NET behind the scenes, which uses the ISO 8601-compatible standard roundtrip date/time string-formatting pattern (`"o"`) that you can pass to the `.ToString()` method of a `[datetime]` instance; e.g., `[datetime]::now.ToString('o')` yields something like:
    `"2020-06-15T11:54:06.114098-04:00"`

    - Example: `@{ dt = [datetime]::now } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`
      yields `{"dt":"2020-06-16T08:07:50.356321-04:00"}`
- On the C# (.NET) side:

  - It seems that at least at some point in the ASP.NET world the old Windows PowerShell convention was used.
  - Json.NET as well as the new .NET-native [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.json) types use the new convention as also used in PowerShell [Core].

---

<sup>[1] Note that the [JSON standard](https://json.org) does *not* define a value type for date/time instances, so it is ultimately up to a given implementation to use *string* JSON values to represent timestamps, as a *convention*; alternatively, a *numeric* representation (such as ticks) is also an option, but only a string representation allows you to *infer* the intended data type (in the absence of schema information).

It is therefore important that both the JSON serializer as well as the JSON deserializer adhere to the same convention in order to pass timestamps properly.</sup>